# Variables in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, pgfmath

I use TikZ to draw graphics in LaTeX. I'd like to do arithmetic on variables. For example I haves nodes named after `N-1` and `N-2` and I'd like to create the `N-3` and `N-4` nodes as `+2` from the first nodes. Something like that:

```
\foreach \y in {1,2}
\node[right of=N-\y] (N-{2+\y}) {x};
```

is not working but is meaning what I want.

---

@jake

OK, that works fine. Now say I want to use it on two variables:

```
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,3/4}
```

and I want to know `\x+\y`

Answer (score 13):

Macros in a node name are merely expanded, but not parsed by a math parser. You need to do this yourself, either by using an explicit command like Marco suggested in his answer, or by using the `[evaluate = <variable> as <new macro> using <expression>]` option of the `\foreach` statement. Note that you want to use the `int(...)` function to make sure the result does not have a trailing `.0` (otherwise your new nodes would be called `N-3.0` and `N-4.0`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (N-1) at (1,1) {N-1};
\node (N-2) at (2,-1) {N-2};
\foreach \y [evaluate = \y as \ypp using int(\y+2)] in {1,2}
    \node[right of=N-\y] (N-\ypp) {N-\ypp};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This also works if you're looping over more than one variable simultaneously:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [text=gray] (N-1) at (1,1) {N-1};
\foreach \x/\y [evaluate = \x as \ypp using int(\y+\x)] in {1/2,3/4}
    \node[right of=N-\x] (N-\ypp) {N-\ypp};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that works fine.
Now say I want to use it on to variables:
    \foreach \x / \y in {1/2,3/4}
and I want to know \x+\y

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand your question:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (N-1) {N-1};
\node[rectangle,draw,below of=N-1] (N-2) {N-2};
\foreach \y in {1,2}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\y+2)}
  \node[right of=N-\y] (N-\pgfmathresult) {x-\pgfmathresult};

  \node[right of=N-4]  {x-4 right};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: Thanks. I will remove the `pgfmathresult`

Answer (score 2):

One more useful example for your reference:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{curly} = [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=2pt]                 

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.append style={inner sep=2pt,text width=50pt,align=center}]
\node [draw,text=gray] (N-1) at (1,1) {$P_1$};
\foreach \x [evaluate = \x as \ypp using int(1+\x)] in {1,...,4}
    \node[rectangle,draw=blue!80,right=0cm of N-\x] (N-\ypp) {$P_\ypp$};
\draw [curly] (N-1.north west)--(N-5.north east) node [black,midway,yshift=14pt] {\footnotesize $T_0$};
\draw [curly] (N-5.south east)--(N-5.south west) node [black,midway,yshift=-14pt] {\footnotesize $T_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]