# Place label in middle of line with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, labels

What is the best way to place a label in the middle of a line with TikZ? I mean smack dab in the middle of the line, not above or below it. The following is close

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[|->, color=red] (-4cm, 0.5cm) -- (2.5cm, 0.5cm) node[midway, color=black] {$\tau_{r}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the line crosses right through the node and its text, which is bad.

I don't know if there is an option to choose the background color of a node, which I think would solve the problem (e.g. `background=white`). `fill` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `fill` key to “delete” the background. As the comments show you must care to set no other color after the fill key with `color` or just using the color name as an option. That will overwrite the color given to `fill`. As you can see in the example `color` set the color for filling, drawing *and* the text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(5,2) node [midway,fill=white] {ABC};
    \draw (3,0) -- ++(5,2) node [midway,fill=white,color=blue] {ABC};
    \draw (6,0) -- ++(5,2) node [midway,fill=white,color=blue,text=white] {ABC};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: color settings]

To change the text or drawing color you can use the `draw` and `text` options, which won’t affect the `fill` color.

```
\node [draw=blue,fill=gray,text=white] {Colors};
```

[image: three colors]

Comment: I actually tried `fill=white`, but I added it before `color=black`. This resulted in the whole box being black. Does order of commands actually matter in TikZ?

Comment: @xiongtx: for me this MWE works perfectly.

Comment: @xiongtx Yes it does.  When you use `color=black` then that is a meta-command which sets *all* colours to black: line colour, fill colour, and text colour.  If you want to override any of those then you have to reset it afterwards.

Comment: As the manual says, if you use `fill` “the area enclosed by the path is filled with the current filling color, which is either the last color set using the general `color=` option or the optional color `⟨color⟩`.” (p. 161) So in you case the last set color wins and overwrites the setting of `fill`.

Comment: (Sorry, can't resist: the order of doing things is more commonly important than not.  That `2+3 = 3+2` ought to be surprising - the fact that it isn't is merely because we're so familiar with it that we don't notice the oddity.  But almost everywhere else, order matters.  In Norway there is a children's song which translates roughly to: "Open window, look out - hello weather, how are you?".  Imagine the difference if you *first* put your head out of the window and *then* opened it.)

Comment: @xiongtx see for instance [Global variables for all tikz drawings in a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42800/global-variables-for-all-tikz-drawings-in-a-document/42818#42818) which discusses this fact amongst other things.