# pgfplots: how to set default number of samples?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

For most of the functions I have to plot with `\addplot` of `pgfplots`, I have to set `[samples=200]` to make them look smooth enough. I was wondering if there is some option to set the default sample number to a specific value so that I don't have to type it over and over again. I could not find one.

Is there such an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables for all tikz drawings in a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42800/global-variables-for-all-tikz-drawings-in-a-document)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many options in the `pgf`, `TikZ` and `pgfplots` family have all their options defaulted in some way. This also means that you can set them wherever you want and obtain a *default*.

In this case you can set the option in the preample or where-ever needed as this:

```
\pgfplotsset{samples=200}
```

This will make all subsequent plots using the `samples` key use 200 samples.

Inspired by cmhughes, for another question I have answered describing the scopes of keys and how they can be used in a short generalized manner, see [Global variables for `TikZ` drawings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42800/global-variables-for-all-tikz-drawings-in-a-document/42818#42818)

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this, but seems I made a typo... sample instead of samples...

Comment: and of course, it can be overwritten locally, e.g `samples=15`

Comment: @cmhughes maybe this is actually a dublicate of my added link?

Comment: @zeroth agreed; +1 for both :)