# How to globally change edge properties using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I want to change all edge properties (to e.g. rounded edges instead of mitered edges) in a tikz picture (*picture globally*), I can do so as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
```

This works fine. However, when attempting to do so for the entire document (*globally*) using tikzset in the preamble (which seemed a logical step after reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42800/global-variables-for-all-tikz-drawings-in-a-document)):

```
\tikzset{line join=round}
```

It does not work, although no error appears, and every tikz image uses the default setting (which is miter) unless otherwise specified locally or picture globally.

Does anyone know how to set this property (and the line cap and miter limit property) globally?

EDIT: as requested a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\tikzset{line join=round} % <-- This does not have any effect

\begin{document}

% Edges are not affected, as they are still 'mitered':
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=black,line width=10pt] coordinates
{(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (4, 0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% This is how it's supposed to look like:
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round] % (!)
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=black,line width=10pt] coordinates
{(0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 0) (3, 1) (4, 0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add to your question a little *complete* document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={line join=round}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `every picture` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={
    line join=round,
    line cap=round,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=10pt]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the `miter limit`, if you try something like

```
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={
    line join=round,
    line cap=round,
    miter limit=25
  }
}
```

you'll see the option has no real effect since the `line join` is selected as `round` for which `miter limit` doesn't apply. Define a style with `line join=miter` and an optional parameter for `miter limit`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    line join=miter,
    miter limit=#1
  },
  mystyle/.default=0 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=10pt]
\draw[mystyle] (0,0) -- ++(5,0.5) -- ++(-5,0.5);
\draw[miter limit=25] (5,0) -- ++(5,0.5) -- ++(-5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the required `every picture` style, it wasn't mentioned in the pgfplots manual.