# How to change default draw color for all styles in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles

Assume I have a `tikzpicture` with different `draw` objects such as lines, circles, rectangle, shapes etc.

When I do not specify a color the default `draw` color is black.

My question is: how can I change the default `draw` color (black) for **all objects in TiKZ picture (scope) to something else**. So it should not change outside tikz picture.

This allow me to quickly (visually) test replacing default black with something else.

Tx

Answer (score 2):

I found it already specify it after tikzpicture.

Excellent explanation on defaults/scope see this site [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42818)

`begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red]`