# Using command as optional argument for tikzpicture-environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.5cm, 0cm)}, y={(0cm, 0.5cm)}, z={(0.25cm, 0.25cm)}]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Works

```
\newcommand{\kosXYZ}{[x=\{(0.5cm, 0cm)\}, y=\{(0cm, 0.5cm)\}, z=\{(0.25cm, 0.25cm)\}]}

\begin{tikzpicture}\kosXYZ
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Doesn't

How and why?

Comment: [Global variables for all tikz drawings in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42800/134144)  and `\tikzset{<options>}` might be interesting.

Comment: `\tikzset{kosXYZ/.style={x={(0.5cm, 0cm)}, y={(0cm, 0.5cm)}, z={(0.25cm, 0.25cm)}}}` and then `\begin{tikzpicture}[kosXYZ]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why it does not work? `\kosXYZ` is not expanded at the time when `\begin{tikzpicture}` 's optional argument is searched. Seems it should be.

Perhaps like this:

```
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\Expandsecond[2]{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{#2}{#1}}%

\newcommand{\kosXYZ}{[x={(0.5cm, 0cm)}, y={(0cm, 0.5cm)}, z={(0.25cm, 0.25cm)}]}

\Expandsecond{\begin{tikzpicture}}{\kosXYZ}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```